# Should we create as many number of files as there are number of apis in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

In next js we have to create a seperate file for each new api like for /user there will be user.js with a seperate handler. And a seperate one for /user/goldmember. Will it not create too much files? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way to route pages in Nextjs. Websites are not built to handle large/excessive number of routes, because it's not really necessary. If you're worried about creating i.e. large number of user endpoints (/user/:id), that's where  [dynamic routes come into play.](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#dynamic-route-segments)

Comment: i am asking about apis not pages

Comment: Same principle applies, though. You also have dynamic catch-all API routes: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes#catch-all-api-routes. Which could be used to handle several API endpoints in a single file.